# How to read Cookie from AuthorizationFilterContext

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorize-attribute

I have a custom Authorize attribute. I need to read a cookie value inside the attribute. How to read cookie from AuthorizationFilterContext as in the below code ? Tried context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["cookieName"] but it is empty.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class IdentityAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public IdentityAuthorizeAttribute(string permissions)
        : base(typeof(IdentityAuthorizeFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { permissions };
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
    }

}

public class IdentityAuthorizeFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{

    public IdentityAuthorizeFilter(string permissions) => Permissions = permissions;
    public string Permissions { get; set; }


    //[Authorize]
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        try
        {
             //Read Cookie
             var cookieVal = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["cookieName"];
        }
     }
```

Comment: `context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies` is the right way.